# Intent opens the app immediately when app is in background -Android

Tags: android, xml

I have a Dialog themed activity that I call on my FirebaseFunction onMessageReceived(), with this I am attempting to display a dialog on the phone's screen if the app is in the background. However:

1- If the app is closed: it works perfectly I can see the dialog in my main screen.

2- If the app is in open, but in the background (I can see it on my recent-apps) it opens the app immediately like if onResume()/onRestart() was called.

I want the dialog to display if app is in the background as  well as when the app is closed, I am sure the problem is on how I am passing the intent, not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should solve your problem.

```
<activity ...
 android:launchMode="singleTop" />

Intent intent= new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

You need to put this new flag!

Comment: Added it to both the android manifest description of the activity, and added the  new flag, sadly it did not work

Comment: try singleInstance instead of singleTop, i cant test the code now sorry

Comment: singleInstance did the  trick, thank you. You are the real Mvp.